# Android canvas.drawPath shows hair lines

Tags: android, canvas, drawing

I have several shapes I draw on the screen. Some shapes are positioned against each other without any space ( according the coordinates ).
My problem is, that I see hair lines between the shapes and I do not understand why ?

Any hints ?

See very small whote lines in the red marked sector.
[image]

Comment: post some code, those hairlines are drawn when you have a `strokeWidth(0)` in the paint you used, which is 1px independent of the canvas matrix

Comment: Your code would be really helpful here.

Comment: Hi Daniel. Playing around with the strokewith dependeding on my scale ( which was the problem ) I managed to avoid theese hair lines. If you like you can post a hint with the strokewidth and I will accept the answer. Thanks